# Purpose of Bin Directory

Tags: linux

Could anyone please describe what the purpose of the **Bin Directory** in Linux is?
I have already had a browse online, but couldn't find a brief, yet comprehensive, answer.

Comment: Try searching Google with the phrase "what is the linux bin directory for". The first hit seems to be pretty clear to me.

Comment: First hit is this question.  Let's remember that Google results change with time and by the user, and this is a site for answering questions.

Answer (score 10):

Bin is an abbreviation of **Binaries**.  It's just a directory where a user of an operating system can expect to find applications.

The different directories on a Linux system can be daunting or confusing if you aren't used to them.  There's a good [overview on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) that explains what each standard directory is for.

Answer (score 0):

It contains essential binary files (unlike `/usr/bin` directory) also for booting. It usually contains the shells like bash and commonly used commands like `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, `cat`, `ls`. 
Unlike `/sbin`, the bin directory contains several useful commands that are of use to both the system administrator as well as non-privileged users.

Comment: In modern Linux, anyway, the distinction between `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is fairly obsolete, though it may hold in some other Unixes. (The original purpose of `/bin` — to hold enough of a system to boot successfully until you could mount `/usr` — is now served by initrd/initramfs; many distributions now put all system applications in `/usr/bin` and make `/bin` a symlink there.)